# groupby.rolling.count() yield `non-unique multi-index` exception

Tags: pandas

I'm using `train_sample.csv` [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/talkingdata-adtracking-fraud-detection/data).

Consider the following:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('train_sample.csv')
df = df.drop(['attributed_time'], axis=1)

df['click_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['click_time'])
df = df.set_index('click_time')
df = df.sort_index()

df['clicks_last_hour'] = df.groupby(['ip']).rolling('1H').count()
```

Where I'm trying to create a new column that counts the number times where a certain `ip` `clicked` in the last hour.

I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train_sample.py", line 11, in <module>
    df['clicks_last_hour'] = df.groupby(['ip']).rolling('1H').count()
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3119, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3194, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3378, in _sanitize_column
    value = reindexer(value).T
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3358, in reindexer
    raise e
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3353, in reindexer
    value = value.reindex(self.index)._values
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 187, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3566, in reindex
    return super(DataFrame, self).reindex(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3689, in reindex
    fill_value, copy).__finalize__(self)
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3501, in _reindex_axes
    fill_value, limit, tolerance)
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3509, in _reindex_index
    tolerance=tolerance)
File "C:\Users\galah\Miniconda3\envs\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\multi.py", line 2068, in reindex
    raise Exception("cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!")
Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!
```

Though from what i checked there are no duplicates based on same `ip` and `click_time`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Going to be hard to say without any sample data or the actual traceback

Comment: @user3483203 added traceback. Can't really show the data as it's too big, but there's a link to download it.